# Miniconda environments taking up ~2 GB each

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I am using SpaceSniffer to try to clean up some space on my drive. I noticed my miniconda folder was about 25 GBs. The "pkgs" subfolder is about 11 GB, which I think makes sense given that I use tensorflow, keras, etc.

What **doesn't** make sense to me is why each separate environment takes up about 2 GBs of space. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how often you update your packages. However, you can always use

```
conda clean --all
```

to remove the index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html

Comment: Thanks for the command - that cleared up 1.7 GB. Why does it depend on how often I update my packages? Do you mean if I have multiple versions in different environments?